# JPA OneToOne insert join column value to entity tables

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have employee table with coloumns:

```
employee_id
department_id
firstname
lastname
address
..
```

And employee_identity table:

```
employee_identity_id
employee_id
ssn
mother_name
father_name
...
```

I have entities of theese tables like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    ...

    // bi-directional one-to-one association to EmployeeIdentity
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private EmployeeIdentity employeeIdentity;

    public Employee() {
        employeeIdentity = new EmployeeIdentity();
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_identity")
@NamedQuery(name = "EmployeeIdentity.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EmployeeIdentity e")
public class EmployeeIdentity implements Serializable {

    ...

    // bi-directional one-to-one association to Employee
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    ...

}
```

I want to create an employee object and set its employeeIdentity's fields and finally persist them. When i commit an employee i can write my data to employee_identity but employee_id coloumn is null. Is this possible or should i commit an employee object and an employeeIdentity object seperately?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong. One side of a bidirectional association MUST be the inverse side, and thus have a `mappedBy` attribute, and no `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` association.

`PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` is also not the correct annotation, since it means: the primary key of this entity is also a join column to another entity. You should have `@JoinColumn` on EmployeeIdentity.employee, which should be the owner side.

And you must take care of initializing the owner side (the side which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute, so `EmployeeIdentity.employee`) if you want JPA to know about the association.